# MassTransit: Queing consumption of different messages for related data

Tags: entity-framework-core, masstransit

**Setup**

I'm using ASPNET Core with EFCore.

I've setup MassTransit to help in the replication of `Users` and `Tokens` between services.

Each `User` has multiple `Tokens` and they are connected by `Token.UserId` foreign key.

**The Issue**

When a new `User` is created, two things happen:

- `User` and fresh `Token` are stored in the database
- `UserCreated` and `TokenCreated` are sent to the message bus **simulatenously**

In effect, `Token` (since it's smaller) is processed before `User` and an error pops saying that `User of given Id defined in Token.UserId doesn't exist in table Users` - which is true, because `User` is created asynchronously along with `Token`.

I've found a few solutions, like removing foreign key constraints or implementing a delay in `Consume` method - both of which seemed to be lazy solutions that'll eventually come back to me.

Is there a way to perhaps put both events on the same queue and execute them in order they are added to it or should I just include the initial Token in `UserCreated`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to message contract design, particularly when producing events...

### Events should be self-contained

Each event should be a complete representation of a specific event. This means that an event should not reference other data sources, should not include foreign keys, and should not require callbacks to a backing service to be able to do something in response to the event.

In your scenario, you may want to either include enough user information in the `TokenCreated` event such that a new user could be added based on the data in that event, or create a third event that includes both data sets – perhaps a `UserTokenCreated`. That third event would be produced when both a new user and new token are created at the same time.

Another option would be to use a saga to combine the two events, but that seems more complexity than you need.

You could also use the broker's delayed message feature to reschedule delivery of the message in the future by some delay instead of simply blocking a consumer slot by using Task.Delay() as you seem to be doing now.

Comment: Hmm, I was thinking about putting Token info inside `UserCreated` event, but that seemed like inevitably binding these resources together - however, just like with CAP Theorem and microservices in general - I might have to take that tradeoff for greater good.

Comment: It's a reasonable trade-off. Honestly, so is removing the FK (which I hardly ever use them anyway). However, I'd focus on NOT having to do joins at the edge/caching layer and would use a flat model to avoid query complexity.

Comment: Absolutely. Thanks for investing the time to help me out.